# Title formatting

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, vertical-alignment, titles, preamble

I have the following code:

```
\title{ \begin{center}
CLAXXX Homework X \newline
Prof. Professor \newline
First Last \newline
Day, Month XX, Year
\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\centering
\maketitle
\newpage
```

I want to centre each line on the page and centre the text block on the page with respect to the top and bottom margins.  I have tried many permutations of stuff, but cannot get this.  Also, I should mention that using LaTeX is not part of the assignment, just something I am doing to help me learn it.  Any help that you can provide is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to centre both horizontally and vertically the title with the `titling` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\title{%
CLAXXX Homework X \\
Prof. Professor \\
First Last
}%
\author{}
\date{Day, Month XX, Year}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\pagestyle{empty}\vfill}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\mbox{}\vfill\clearpage}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following code; it does what you want in my system. However the title is  going to be centered vertically only if the format is "book"; for the regular article format a modification is necessary and therefore is also necessary a whole page for the title.

> \title{
>   CLAXXX Homework X \\
>   Prof. Professor \\
>   First Last \\
>   Day, Month XX, Year
>   }

- possible solution for article class without additional package

> \documentclass{article}
>   \title{\vspace{6cm}
>   CLAXXX Homework X \\
>   Prof. Professor \\
>   First Last \\
>   Day, Month XX, Year
>   }
>   
>   \begin{document}
>   \maketitle
>   \thispagestyle{empty}
>   
>   \newpage
>   
>   \part{part I}
>   
>   text
>   
>   \end{document}